# Why some pinned UV vertices have black dots on them?

Tags: uv

I've long noticed some of the pinned UV vertices have a black dot amidst them, and at first I thought I was seeing two UV vertices sharing location, but that doesn't seem to be the case as it's only selectable as a single entity.

Does anybody have any clue about why is it so?

[image]